# Bypassing Angular URL routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I bypass the routing provided by angular? For instance, in my angular routing settings, I have set `$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo : '/someurl'});`.

I want a certain request (generated by the user clicking a certain link in the HTML) to go to my webserver and not redirected to `/someurl` by Angular's routing. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

From the [$location docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location#hashbang-and-html5-modes_html5-mode_html-link-rewriting):

> In cases like the following, links are not rewritten; instead, the
>   browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.
>
> **Links that contain target element. Example: `<a href="/ext/link?a=b"
>   target="_self">link</a>`**
>
> Absolute links that go to a different domain. Example: `<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
>
> Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base is defined. Example:
>   `<a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>`

Comment: I've tried this. If I open the links in a new tab, it works fine. But if I click on the link directly, angular's routing takes over, none the less.

Comment: You should create a plunker. Here's a [template](http://plnkr.co/edit/cXfgcjb61r6AU5EdFXyu?p=preview).

Comment: The problem occurs only when the html5 mode is set to true. With the #  based url scheme, it works fine.