# Switch _layout.cshtml using angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm using angularjs and .NET MVC together. I'm using an initial _layout.cshtml page, but the rest of the routing is through angular.

However, for the login page, I want a different layout page and I can't figure out how to break-out of the angular routing and get back to the _viewStart.cshtml to pick another layout. In the _viewStart, I have something like this, but I never get to the _viewStart after angular starts to take over the routing.

```
@{
  if(Request.Path.Contains("Login")) {
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml";
  }
  else { 
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
}
```

Comment: Bypassing angular routing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657593/bypassing-angular-url-routing

Comment: In what page you are using the ng-view directive

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437355/how-to-redirect-pages-in-asp-mvc-using-angularjs

Comment: @Riv- thanks, but that doesn't seem to work when in html5 mode.

Comment: @ModarNa, I'll try the window.location. That should work, thanks!

Comment: @ModarNa- that worked!